# Parsing XML data into C# using XmLReader

Tags: c#, xml

I am doing my school project about using weather data on http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=17 and I just need temperature.
Here is an example:

```
<time day="2014-05-01">
   <symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"/>
   <precipitation value="0.5" type="rain"/>
   <temperature day="7.6" min="6.8" max="7.6" night="6.8" eve="7.6" morn="7.6"/>
   <clouds value="overcast clouds" all="88" unit="%"/>
</time>
```

I have two problems:
 + I do not know how to take the day temperature and parse it into my variable. I tried this one, but it did not work:

```
string temperature = " ";
while (myXmlReader.Read())
  {
    if (myXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && myXmlReader.Name == "time")
     {
       if (myXmlReader.HasAttributes)
         {
           if (myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day") != null)
             {
               if (myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day") == day)
                 {
                   if (myXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && myXmlReader.Name == "temperature")
                      {
                        if(myXmlReader.HasAttributes)
                         {
                            if (myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day") != null)
                              {
                                  temperature = myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day"); 
                              }
                         }
                       }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
   }
 Response.Write("temperature = " + temperature + "<br/>");
```

The variable `temperature` when print is null.

- I have variable `city` which contains the information the users enter (from HTML form) that I want to put it to the link. Therefore I use another variable `link`:

  `string link = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+city+"&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=17"`

And then I request the page by using:

```
 WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(link);
```

and then, there is a problem at

```
while (myXmlReader.Read())
```

it says {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}. This does not happen when I do not use the variable `link` and add the link directly like this:

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=17");
```

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Something about the variable `city`:

```
<form>
City: <select name="city">
    <option value="Helsinki">Helsinki</option>
    <option value="Lahti">Lahti</option>
    <option value="Tampere">Tampere</option>
    <option value="Oulu">Oulu</option>
    <option value="Rovaniemi">Rovaniemi</option>
    <option value="Espoo">Espoo</option>
    <option value="Vantaa">Vantaa</option>
</select> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit to see the result"/>
</form>
<%string city = Request["city"]%>
```

Comment: you should probably look at XDocument. Use streamreader to load the xml.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318876/Using-the-XmlReader-class-with-Csharp   Check this article Especialy the section which reads data with XmlReader. You can also use XMLDocument class.

Comment: What is the value of `city` if you debug?

Comment: @rene for example it can be London if you want.

Comment: All these nested if statements make me cry in agony. This is truly terrible code, especially because you repeat many statements. Never, every do that.

Comment: @dirkk it's funny looking back at this. I was so bad back then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed in your processing of the elements that once you find the `time` element you can't **ALSO** be on the `temperature` element. You have to continue reading the xml document until you find that element. I combined several if's to condense your code a little bit but this does work:

```
var city="London";
var url = String.Format(
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={0}&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=17"
            , city);

string temperature = String.Empty;
string  day ="2014-05-02";

using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    using(var stream = wc.OpenRead(url))
    {
        using(var myXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
        {
            while (myXmlReader.Read())
            {
                 // <time day="2014-05-01">
                if (myXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
                    && myXmlReader.Name == "time"
                    && myXmlReader.HasAttributes
                    && myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day") == day)
                {
                    // find the inner elements    
                    while (myXmlReader.Read())
                    {
                        // skip <symbol> <precipitation> <windDirection>  
                        //  and <windSpeed>
                        if (myXmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
                            && myXmlReader.Name == "temperature"
                            && myXmlReader.HasAttributes
                            && myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day") != null)
                        {
                            // <temperature day="7.83" min="6.76" max="7.83" 
                            //   night="6.76" eve="7.83" morn="7.83"/>
                            temperature = myXmlReader.GetAttribute("day"); 
                            break;  // stop reading!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of reading the elements with an XmlReader you could use an XDocument and leveraging Linq to get the nodes you need:

```
string  WheaterFromXDocument()
{
    var city="London";
    var url = String.Format(
                "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={0}&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=17"
                , city);

    string temperature = String.Empty;
    string  day ="2014-05-02";

    using(var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        using(var stream = wc.OpenRead(url))
        {
            var dayAttr  = (from  time in XDocument.Load(stream).Descendants("time")
                        where (string) time.Attribute("day") == day
                        from tempElem in time.Elements("temperature")
                        select tempElem.Attribute("day"))
                        .SingleOrDefault();
            if (dayAttr!=null)
            {
                temperature = dayAttr.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    return temperature;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But it also says {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."} at `while (myXmlReader.Read())`. I have no idea why?

Comment: That might be because your city variable is empty or not correct. If you debug up to the point where the url is created you can check the value of the complete url. Or you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see which requests are sent. Or you can add a Trace.Write(city); in your code (assuming this is asp.net) and then visit /trace.axd as explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wwh16c6c(v=vs.100).aspx). Your bug is not in the code you shown. It went wrong earlier.

Comment: I am doing an web application, so the city will be decide by the users (with select form of some cities available). Therefore, the variable `city` will not assign any value before the web can be loaded.

Comment: You better ask a new question about the city var being empty. Make sure your question shows the aspx markup and the codebehind. You should first debug your code yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w9dfyd8.aspx